# Terminology for tree-like proofs

Tags: logic

In a tree-like proof what is the term for the  number of steps between any node and the root (the statement proved by the proof)?  That is, if numb were this term, then one would have depth of tree = max(numb(leaf)), where the max is taken over all leaves in the tree.

Comment: I would just call it the depth of a node, personally. Although I have no idea whether that's convention.

Comment: OK thanks. In googling I see at least some people use that term, so I guess I will use it.

Answer (score 0):

The steps between the root node and a leaf node (or more precisely, a maximal linearly ordered subset of the set of nodes) is called a **branch**. The number of steps (minus 1) is called the **length** of the branch - this is the term you're looking for. The **depth** or **height** of a tree is the maximum length of it's branches, as you correctly conjectured. The **length** of a tree would be the number of nodes in it.